# MySQL: find users that registered on site & then bought same day

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to capture the number of users that register on our site and then buy something that same day. Getting a little lost on my query. It is returning results, but upon closer inspection (these are loafers) the results are not correct.

I have 2 tables: `customer` and `purchase`. Both tables have `customer_id` and `date` (for the customer table the date is "date_created" and purchase table is "date_modified").

Basically I want to get an aggregate count each day of user_ids that were created in the `customer_id` table and then had purchase appear in the `purchase` table that same day. *Note: there's also a condition where I don't want to include purchases from customer_id 1. customer_id 1 is a test account that is used sometimes to make purchases for testing purposes on the site.

This is what I tried:

```
select 
    date_format(c.`date_created`, '%Y-%m-%d') as day_date
    ,x.same_day_purchase

from `customer` c

left join (
    select 
        p.`customer_id`
        ,p.`date_modified`
        ,sum(if(p.`date_modified` >= cp.`date_created`,1,0)) as same_day_purchase
    from purchase p
    inner join `customer` cp on p.`customer_id` = cp.`customer_id` and p.`customer_id`<>1

group by cp.`date_created`
            ) x on c.`customer_id` = x.`customer_id` and x.`customer_id`<>1


where (c.`date_created` >= '2011/09/01' and c.`date_created` < '2014/05/14')
group by day_date
```

(So the result I'd be looking for is:

2011/09/01 - 3

2011/09/02 - 16

etc.

So on 9/1/2011 3 users came to our site and registered, then bought something that same day. The next day we had 16 people newly registered customers buy products, and so on....)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT DATE(c.date_created) AS `date`
       ,COUNT(DISTINCT c.customer_id) AS registered_customers_who_bought
FROM customer AS c
JOIN purchase AS p
  ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
    AND DATE(c.date_created) = DATE(p.date_modified)
WHERE (c.`date_created` >= '2011/09/01' and c.`date_created` < '2014/05/14')
GROUP BY DATE(c.date_created)
```

Comment: that did it, I guess I was really overthinking the query- this one is way simpler, thanks

Answer (score 1):

here is a starting point for you:

```
select date(date_created)
       ,count(distinct c.customer_id)
from customer c
join purchase p using (customer_id)
where DATEDIFF(p.date_modified,c.date_created) = 0
       and c.date_created between '2011/09/01' and now()
       and c.customer_id <> 1
group by date(c.date_created)
```